# Save choice and execute later in pgfkeys?

Tags: pgfkeys

Using pgfkeys, I would like to have a choice key which, rather than immediately executing some code when a value is selected, stores the selection somewhere and then later on demand I can execute the code associated with said option.

An example should clarify things. I would like to define some sort of handler that allows me to write something like:

```
\pgfkeys{
  /action/.is choice,
  /action/jump/.on exec = \dojump,
  /action/walk/.on exec = \dowalk,
  /action/run/.on exec  = \dorun
}
```

So that when I select an option

```
\pgfkeys{/action=jump} # remembers that I selected "jump"
```

the corresponding code `\dojump` is *not* executed just yet, but instead the selection is saved and executed only later until I actually say something like:

```
\pgfkeys{/action/.exec} # actually does the `\dojump`
```

This should allow the user to choose one option at some point, and change her mind later, and then put the option back. But nothing should be executed until I explicitly ask the code for the selected option to be executed.

Is there a simple way to add handlers to pgfkeys and achieve this? Am I doing things the right way, or I am trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I can't see what `\pgfkeys@split@path` is doing here, since you aren't using `\pgfkeyscurrentname` and `\pgfkeys@case@three` calls `\pgfkeys@split@path`. And `do exec/.style={\pgfkeyscurrentpath/do exec}` smacks of a cyclic call.

Comment: `\pgfkeys@split@path` splits the current key into path+name; by setting the path to the current key before calling this, effectively this moves the path “one level up”. And the “cyclic call” is no cyclic, precisely for the same reason, I do a .cd up to go one leve up before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a few more iterations of my original ideas, I've implemented a solution with which I'm pretty comfortable now, and which is stable enough so that I'm happy to share it as well.

I've turned this  into a small package [ezkeys](https://github.com/navarroj/ezlatex/blob/master/ezkeys.sty), which is a single file containing mostly documentation and a bit of code defining some new pgfkey handlers.

As an example usage, after setting:

```
\pgfkeys{
  my package/.is family,
  my package,
  align/.is code choice,
  align/left/.code   = \raggedright,
  align/center/.code = \centering,
  align/right/.code  = \raggedleft,
  format/.is code choice,
  format/bold/.code    = \textbf{#1},
  format/italics/.code = \textit{#1},
}
```

Options can be selected using, e.g.:

```
\pgfkeys{my package,align=right,format=bold}
```

which causes the selected options to remebered but *not* executed. Only later, when requesting it by explcitly evaluating

```
\pgfkeys{my package,align/.eval,/format/.eval=Hello}
```

then corresponding subkeys will be executed and expanded, in this example to

```
\raggedleft\textbf{Hello}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution (2012/11/02)**

I don't think we need *pgfkeys* for this task, but here is an attempt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\def\elk@do#1{\@ifnextchar x#1#1}
\def\elk@@do#1#2#3{%
  \csname @\ifx#1#2gobble\else iden\fi\endcsname
  {#3\elk@do#1}%
}
\def\foreachelk#1#2{%
  \def\elkdo##1,{\elk@@do\elkdo{##1}{#2}}%
  \elk@do\elkdo#1,\elkdo,%
}
\def\foreachbison#1#2{%
  \def\bisondo##1/##2,{\elk@@do\bisondo{##1}{#2}}%
  \elk@do\bisondo#1,\bisondo/,%
}
\def\pgfkeys@everystartchoice{}
\def\pgfkeyseverysoc{\g@addto@macro\pgfkeys@everystartchoice}
\def\pgfkeys@everyendchoice{}
\def\pgfkeyseveryeoc{\g@addto@macro\pgfkeys@everyendchoice}
\let\nava@choicewrapper\@iden
\def\choicewrapper{\gdef\nava@choicewrapper}
\pgfkeys{
  /nava/action/.is family,
  /nava/action/.cd,
  .define choices/.code={%
    \foreachbison{#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{%
        /nava/action/##1/.code={%
          \ifcsname nava-##1\endcsname
            \@latexerr{Choice '##1' already defined}\@ehd
          \else
            \expandafter\edef\csname nava-##1\endcsname{%
              \unexpanded\expandafter{\pgfkeys@everystartchoice}%
              \unexpanded{\nava@choicewrapper{##2}}%
              \unexpanded\expandafter{\pgfkeys@everyendchoice}%
            }%
          \fi
        },
        /nava/action/##1,
      }%
    }%
  },
  .exec method/.code={%
    \foreachelk{#1}{\csname nava-##1\endcsname}%
  },
}
% \addnewchoices{<choice1/method1,choice2/method2,...>}
\def\addnewchoices#1{\pgfkeys{/nava/action/.define choices={#1}}}
\def\dochoicemethods#1{\pgfkeys{/nava/action/.exec method={#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% These are optional. Insert at end of every choice:
\pgfkeyseveryeoc{.\endgraf}
% Wrap the methods for the choices:
\choicewrapper{\textit}

% Define and remember my choices:
\addnewchoices{jump/I'll jump,walk/I'll walk,run/I'm running home}

% Call my choices and execute their methods:
\dochoicemethods{jump,walk,run,run,walk}
\dochoicemethods{jump}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, that is what I want to achieve. However (1) I don't want to have to invent a new name (`\navaaction`) for each similar option that I may want to define. It feels that something like `/navarro/action/exec` is already a good name that shouldn't clash with other packages. And (2) I'm lazy, if I do this over and over again, I don't want to be writing `\def\navaaction` all the time. That's why I think it would be better to define a handler that does all the work for me.

Comment: You can get rid of the macro by writing, say, `action/jump/.style = {exec/.code = \dojump}`.

Comment: And what should I use to call the last action *selected* by the user?

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro: The last question isn't clear to me.

Comment: @AhmedMusa, sorry for that. I guess I could have explained myself better. Anyway, thanks for your help, now I've updated my question with something that looks like a solution to me. Would you like to comment on that?

Answer (score 2):

This type of deferred evaluation can be easily achieved by making each choice a `.style` which assigns the desired code to the helper key `.exec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\dojump{jump}
\newcommand\dowalk{walk}
\newcommand\dorun{run}

\pgfkeys{
  /action/.is choice,
  /action/jump/.style={/action/.exec/.code={\dojump}},
  /action/walk/.style={/action/.exec/.code={\dowalk}},
  /action/run/.style={/action/.exec/.code={\dorun}}
}

\pgfkeys{/action=jump} % remembers that I selected "jump"

\pgfkeys{/action/.exec} % actually does the `\dojump`

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question. In my current project I encounter situations that would require this behavior very often. However, I think a simpler solution is possible than the one you propose.

Here is how it works:

- First, we define a new handler which can be used like `/some/key/.is deferred choice`. This executes `/some/key/.is choice` and also defines a *'mirror key'* `/deferred choice/code/some/key/.is choice`. This mirror key will have the *same* choices, which will store the actual code.
- The individual options are then defined with `/some/key/<choice>/.deferred code={<code>}`. This stores the `<code>` in `/deferred choice/code/some/key/<choice>/.code` and sets up `/some/key/<choice>/.code` to only store the value for later use.
- When setting `/some/key=<choice>`, the value `<choice>` is stored in the key `/deferred choice/value/some/key` using `\pgfkeyssetvalue`.
- When running `/some/key/.execute=#1`, the value `<choice>` from `/deferred choice/value/some/key` is loaded, in order to then find and execute the key `/deferred choice/code/some/key/<choice>={#1}`.

And here is the compiled output of the example. As you can see, setting `align=right, format=bold` did not output anything, since the execution of the actual code was deferred until `.execute` was run.

[image: Compiled output of the example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeysdef{/handlers/.deferred code}{% is called with \pgfkeyscurrentpath=/path/ChoiceKey/ChoiceValue
    \pgfkeysdef{/deferred choice/code\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{#1}%
    \edef\pgfkeyscurrentkey{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}\pgfkeys@split@path% now path=/path/ChoiceKey and name=ChoiceValue
    \pgfkeysedef{\pgfkeyscurrentkey}{\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/deferred choice/value\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\pgfkeyscurrentname}}%
}
\makeatother
\pgfkeysdef{/handlers/.is deferred choice}{%
    \expandafter\pgfkeysedef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.execute}{% is called with \pgfkeyscurrentpath=/path/ChoiceKey
        \noexpand\pgfkeysgetvalue{/deferred choice/value\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\noexpand\temp}%
        \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{/deferred choice/code\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\noexpand\temp={##1}}%
    }
    \pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.is choice}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/deferred choice/code\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.is choice}%
}

\begin{document}
  \pgfkeys{
      /my package/.is family,
      /my package,
      align/.is deferred choice,
      align/left/.deferred code   = left:,
      align/right/.deferred code  = right:,
      format/.is deferred choice,
      format/bold/.deferred code    = bold:{#1},
      format/italics/.deferred code = italics:{#1},
  }
  \pgfkeys{/my package, align=right, format=bold}
  \pgfkeys{/my package, align=left, format=italics}
  %\pgfkeys{/my package, align=wrong} % Error: Choice 'wrong' unknown in choice key '/my package/align'
  \pgfkeys{/my package, align/.execute, format/.execute=Hello}
\end{document}
```