# Parametric Pics : Variations of Infinity

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, parameters

Let's argue that I want to draw variations of the infinity symbol (Mostly because I can't draw ducks although it makes for a good MWE). I can't find a simple example that uses pgf/tikz keys to manipulate how a tikz pic is drawn in a concise manner. Looking over my own code base it looks like I'm rather confused about the topic myself.

### Requirements :

Let's allow the size of the shape to be altered by the keys `width` and `height` and enable some wobble in the lobes with the keys `inner target`and `outer target`. Most importantly we want to select between various calligraphic pens, which must be set by code. This is controlled by selecting `left` and 'right' for the `pen`.

### Code :

For this example you will need the `spath` and `calligraphy` style files, <s>available [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files)</s>, available as the `spath3` package and tikz `calligraphy` libraries.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{spath}
\usepackage{calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
 infinity/.is family,
 infinity/.pic = {
  % This is the curve we wish to have drawn
  \calligraphy let \p1=(0,0) in 
     (\p1) .. controls (-\infty@upper*\infty@width, \infty@height) and (-\infty@lower*\infty@width,-\infty@height) .. 
     (\p1) .. controls ( \infty@lower*\infty@width, \infty@height) and ( \infty@upper*\infty@width,-\infty@height) .. cycle;;
  % This curve is simply here as a backup
  \draw[line width=0.1, blue] let \p1=(0,0) in 
     (\p1) .. controls (-\infty@upper*\infty@width, \infty@height) and (-\infty@lower*\infty@width,-\infty@height) .. 
     (\p1) .. controls ( \infty@lower*\infty@width, \infty@height) and ( \infty@upper*\infty@width,-\infty@height) .. cycle;;
 },
 infinity,
 pen/.is choice,
 pen/left/.code={\pen (-.01,.01) -- (.01,-.01);},
 pen/right/.code={\pen (-.01,-.01) -- (.01,.01);},
 pen/.default=left,
 pen/.initial=left,
 width/.store in=\infty@width,
 height/.store in=\infty@height,
 inner target/.store in=\infty@upper,
 outer target/.store in=\infty@lower,
}
\tikzset{
 infinity,
 width        =   1 em,
 height       =   1 em,
 inner target = 0.2 em,
 outer target = 0.8 em,
}
%\tikzset{ % Fails to set the properties before the infinity/.code is executed.
% infinity/.style={width=1em, height=1em, inner target =0.2, outer target =0.8},
%}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw pic {infinity};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw pic[infinity/pen=left] {infinity};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Overview

I am trying to structure the code as follows. Group everything under the `infinity` family. `infinity` also acts as the tikz pic whose geometry is controlled by the dimensions `\infty@DIMENSION`, where `DIMENSION` is one of `width` and `height`, controlling the size, and `upper` and `lower`, controlling the wobble. The `pen` is selected as described above.

### Question(s) :

1. How does one set the defaults for the pic setting ? Setting the geometry keys in `infinity/.style` fails for me. I've therefore defined them the second `\tikzset{}` call so that the MWE compiles out of the box.
2. I also have to explicitly set the value pen for the calligraphic curve to display. Shouldn't this also be made part of the `infinity/.style` ?
3. This point relates to 1 and 2 above. Setting the dimensions under `infinity/.style` fails, as it does not set any of the dimensions before `infinity/.code` is executed.

   `\tikzset{
    infinity/.style={...},
   }`
4. In some other code I have I use the `DIMENISON/.get` handler instead of 'DIMENSION/.store in' handler. Should I be doing this here ?
5. In the second `tikzpicture` environment I explicitly set pen using `infinity/pen=...` is there a way I could simply write `pen=...` ? Is it then also necessary to specify `infinity/.search also=/tikz/` in the first `\tikzset` where I define `infinity` ?

### Background :

There was a very good answer by Ryan Reich regarding some of this stuff but I can't find it now. I have read through the pgfkeys section of the pgfmanual, to me it reads more like an API document and I find I need an example to connect the dots, hence this question.

### Update :

My original intention with this question has been userped by a package update, which is really nice in a "Oh darn" kind of way.

Comment: Select the 'Users' pick on the top menu, then search for Reich.  You would quickly find this answer. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values/34318#34318

Comment: @R.Schumacher I did go through that route, thanks. I reread a few of his answers again today but did not see the answer I was looking for when I decided to post the question. I think I made a note somewhere of it but then I'd need to find the note ^_^. The main idea here is to get a nice example showing how to set choices, append code that may be used to modify the pic and then provide a few base dimensions so the pic is easily scaled in some way that deviates from how the overall picture is scaled.

Comment: What was the package update that usurped your original intention?

Comment: They converted the pen commands into options for the calligraphy command. I've posted potential answer that handles the case that this key is not present. It was one of the things I wanted to understand when I posted the question but after reviewing the question this wasn't particularly clear it was sort of spread across points 1 - 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *basic* rule with keys (there are exceptions) is that you need to do the following things:

1. Initialise a key,
2. Define a key,
3. Use a key.

On the whole, I find that once I'm in the `pgfkeys` ecosystem then it is best to stay there.  So the values `height`, `width`, `upper`, and `lower` can be stored in keys rather than needing auxiliary macros.

With the pen, when you use a `.code` key then that code is executed when it is invoked so it is a little different to storing values for later use.  What you wanted was to decide which pen to use and then inside the `pic` invoke the code necessary to install it.  This means separating the setting and getting of that key since you want to set the key in the options to the `pic` but use it in the actual code.  This means it would be easier to use `pen` to set an option which says which pen to use later on.  In fact, you could define the pens at the start of the document and use them in your code.

1. Using `infinity/.style` means that you are using the `infinity` key in three different ways: as a pgfkeys family, as a pic, and as a style.  This is possibly a little too confusing for the user.  Using keys, it's not necessary to also use styles.  You can set initial values for the keys with the `.initial` key handler.
2. By making the pen a value rather than explicit code, we can use the `.initial` key handler for this as well.
3. The reason `infinity/.style` doesn't do anything is that you never use it.
4. Using the keys themselves avoids needing the `.store in` or `.get` handlers.
5. You can set `pen` to be an alias to `infinity/pen` as in the code below.

Here's working code, feel free to ask follow-up questions in the comments:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315412/86}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,calligraphy}

\makeatletter
%
% This is a shorthand for getting the value of a relevant key, purely
% to save typing
%
\def\inf@key#1{%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/infinity/#1}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  %
  % Put these in a box to throw away so that it takes up no space
  %
  \setbox0=\vbox{%
    \definepen[pen name=left] (-.01,.01) -- (.01,-.01);
    \definepen[pen name=right] (-.01,-.01) -- (.01,.01);
  }%
}

\tikzset{
  %
  % So that we can use the pen outside the infinity tree
  %
  pen/.style={
    infinity/pen=#1,
  },
  infinity/.is family,
  infinity/.pic = {
    %
    % The calligraphy/spath3 library currently has some issues with the
    % cycle coordinate.  Oops.
    %
    \calligraphy[pen name=\inf@key{pen}] let \p1=(0,0) in 
     (\p1) .. controls (-\inf@key{inner target}*\inf@key{width}, \inf@key{height}) and (-\inf@key{outer target}*\inf@key{width},-\inf@key{height}) .. 
     (\p1) .. controls ( \inf@key{outer target}*\inf@key{width}, \inf@key{height}) and ( \inf@key{inner target}*\inf@key{width},-\inf@key{height}) .. (\p1);
    % This curve is simply here as a backup
    \draw[line width=0.1, blue] let \p1=(0,0) in 
     (\p1) .. controls (-\inf@key{inner target}*\inf@key{width}, \inf@key{height}) and (-\inf@key{outer target}*\inf@key{width},-\inf@key{height}) .. 
     (\p1) .. controls ( \inf@key{outer target}*\inf@key{width}, \inf@key{height}) and ( \inf@key{inner target}*\inf@key{width},-\inf@key{height}) .. (\p1);
  },
  infinity,
  pen/.initial=left,
  width/.initial=1em,
  height/.initial=1em,
  inner target/.initial=0.2,
  outer target/.initial=0.8
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw pic[infinity/width=2em] {infinity};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw pic[infinity/pen=right] {infinity};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pen=right] pic {infinity};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, the `spath` library was superseded by the `spath3` library which is available from CTAN and available in all good TeX distributions.

Comment: If one wanted to allow the specification of width/height/upper/lower as pic options i.e. `pic[height=2,pen=left] {infinity}` does one have to map each dimension to it's own style as is done with `pen/.style={...}` ? That was why I made infinity it's own style and asked about the `.search also` handler. Perhaps if pic provided it's own scope one could then do `infinity/.pic={[infinity, pic actions] ...}` or  `infinity/.pic={\begin{scope}[infinity, pic actions] ... \end{scope}}`. As you point out I was not invoking `infinity/.style` anywhere. Perhaps this is a bad idea.

Comment: @Carel You could do `pic[infinity,height=2,pen=left]` since the first `infinity` shifts the path to the `infinity` sub-tree.  If you want to mix `infinity` and normal styles then you need the `search also` stuff.  NB the `pic` stuff is relatively new and I for one am finding that not everything works as I expect it to so I end up with lots and lots of experiments as I try to figure it out!  So carry on trying.

Comment: From the docs the optional argument in pic gets wrapped into `pic actions` so having something like `\calligraphy[infinity, pic actions]` within the pic code should allow this to pass through into the `infinity` scope/branch. Trying this still turns out a few errors for me either related to expansion of `pic actions` or it just exceeds TeX's capacity.

Comment: I've since [formalized](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315672/14593) my last question.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with the older packages I was able to resolve something I was curious about. Namely how does one optionally change the pen when specifying the pic.

Following the advice @Loop Space provided, namely don't mush all of ones keys together under one path, actually use the styles you define, store ones values in the pgf tree and provide a wrapper macro to retrieve them.  Results in the following, albeit slightly verbose version of his answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{spath}
\usepackage{calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\def\inf@key#1{%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/infinity dimensions/#1}%
}    
\tikzset{
 % Dimensions
 infinity dimensions/.is family,
 infinity dimensions/width/.initial =1 em,
 infinity dimensions/height/.initial=1 em,
 infinity dimensions/upper target/.initial=0.2,
 infinity dimensions/lower target/.initial=0.8,
 % Options
 infinity options/.is family,
 infinity options/pen/.is choice,
 infinity options/pen/left/.code  = {\pen (-.01, .01) -- ( .01,-.01);},
 infinity options/pen/right/.code = {\pen (-.01,-.01) -- ( .01, .01);},
 infinity options/pen/.default=left,
 % Style
 infinity style/.style={/tikz/infinity options/.cd, pen=#1},
 % Pic/Symbol
 infinity symbol/.pic = {
  % This is the curve we wish to have drawn
  \calligraphy[infinity style=#1] let \p1=(0,0) in 
     (\p1) .. controls (-\inf@key{upper target}*\inf@key{width}, \inf@key{height}) and (-\inf@key{lower target}*\inf@key{width},-\inf@key{height}) .. 
     (\p1) .. controls ( \inf@key{lower target}*\inf@key{width}, \inf@key{height}) and ( \inf@key{upper target}*\inf@key{width},-\inf@key{height}) .. cycle;
  % This curve is simply here as a backup
  \draw[line width=0.1, blue] let \p1=(0,0) in 
     (\p1) .. controls (-\inf@key{upper target}*\inf@key{width}, \inf@key{height}) and (-\inf@key{lower target}*\inf@key{width},-\inf@key{height}) .. 
     (\p1) .. controls ( \inf@key{lower target}*\inf@key{width}, \inf@key{height}) and ( \inf@key{upper target}*\inf@key{width},-\inf@key{height}) .. cycle;
 },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw pic {infinity symbol};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw pic {infinity symbol=right};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The difference being that I deliberately kept the `.is choice` handler, set up the `.style` and *importantly* used it. (EZKeys provides an alternate [approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80015/14593)). The *magic* happens with the line(s) `infinity style/.style={...}` and `\calligraphy[infinity style=#1] ...` which enable the optional argument specified in `\draw pic {infinity symbol= ...}`. These act together to passing the argument through to the correct branch/name space within pgfkeys. The `\pen ...;` code is then called before the calligraphy path is traced, which was not happening in the original question.

I have not managed to resolve the passing of `pic actions` to `infinity dimensions` just yet.

It would be beneficial to have a version with all the keys "mushed" together for comparison which is possible as the handlers do not in general clash. It also saves one from naming branches like `infinity symbol/options/dimensions`, which should really belong in an `infinity` sub-tree/branch.

This was more of an exercise but it could be useful as it allows 'classes' of pic. As an example if I specified a series of car related pics I could provide a default, say a volla (Beetle), for `\draw pic {car};` but allow one to select an alternate  `\draw pic {car=ALTERNATE};` such as a hotrod, saloon or hatchback.