# Tikz/pgfkeys: automatically execute code at the end of option processing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, pgfkeys

How can I automatically execute a code in a tikz/pgf option when all options are processed? I want to execute a command a single time, say `updateValueShouldBeCalledOnce` (that reads some variable sets by previous options (`sayBye`/`sayHello`, potentially present multiple times)) as it fails if it's run twice, so for now I need to write `\rar[sayBye,updateValueShouldBeCalledOnce]`, but I'd rather write:

```
\rar[sayBye]
```

How could I do that?

**MWE** (to check if the function is called once or twice, check at the log, it displays a message everytime the function is called)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\def\myvalue{}
\noindent\begin{tikzcd}[
  updateValueShouldBeCalledOnce/.code={%
    \message{The message is: \myvalue}%
  },
  sayBye/.code={%
    \def\myvalue{^^J^^JBye!!!!!^^J^^J}% I don't want to call updateValueShouldBeCalledOnce here as it might be called several times
  },
  sayHello/.code={%
    \def\myvalue{^^J^^JHello!!!!!^^J^^J}% I don't want to call updateValueShouldBeCalledOnce here as it might be called several times
  },
  nodes in empty cells=true,
  every arrow/.style={
    ->,
    draw,
    sayHello
  },
  ]
  \text{I want to do this} & \\
  A \rar[updateValueShouldBeCalledOnce] & B \rar[sayBye,updateValueShouldBeCalledOnce] & C\\
  \text{But with this syntax} & \\
  A \rar & B \rar[sayBye] & C
\end{tikzcd}



\end{document}
```

Note that I'm aware of [Save choice and execute later in pgfkeys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80015/save-choice-and-execute-later-in-pgfkeys) but it actually wants something different, as I'd like the differed action to be automatically run after reading all options.

Comment: Generally speaking, I don't think you can. You will have to compromise somewhere. What are you trying to achieve on the TikZ-CD level? Here, I suggest defining your own command: `\newcommand\myarrow[1][]{\arrow[#1,updateValueShouldBeCalledOnce]}`. With a bit patch work, we can hide this from the user (so that the normal commands can be used) if necessary.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel ok thanks, I guess I'll do that then (basically, I want to put all edges on a special layer by default, but the styles I got to change the layers are not really resilient to being changed multiple times).

Comment: Layers as in [PGF Layers](https://tikz.dev/base-layers), i.e. foreground/background stuff? An inflexible version of this consists in [`\bgarrow`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664328) where an arrow will be put onto the `background` layer. Which would be just a specialized version of `\arrowOnLayer{layername}[<normal options>]`. Though, with filtered PGFkeys we could process the options to `\arrow` twice, once to figure out which layer should be used and then for the normal TikZ path.